# TFS 2015 report that list the dates of state changes of a bug

Tags: reporting-services, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem

I am using the reporting and analysis server for TFS. I am NOT a reporting expert. Is there an out-of-the-box report that will capture/list the dates of all the state changes of a workitem?

The PMs want to see the history of a workitem?

Comment: ssrs is meant for presentation anyway.. so you could use SQL or the like to query the data? Once you have the data.. report writing should be fairly straight forward?

Comment: Here's the [Microsoft Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/devops/report/excel/create-status-and-trend-excel-reports?view=tfs-2018) for Excel TFS reports

Comment: But I'm not sure if the data warehouse has the times when the state changes occur. If it does, that's awesome, but I wouldn't have a clue how to get that data out for a report.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box reports for you tasks. Maybe these steps will be useful for you:

1. Report with SQL Report Builder and Olap
2. Run SQL Report Builder connected to Report Server with Wizard:
   [image]
3. Select create dataset
   [image]
4. Select Olap Connection or find it with browse
   [image]
5. Select the Work Item Cube
   [image]
6. Add the Work Item Count Measure
   [image]
7. Add fields to report
   [image]
8. Add the Team Project Name to the filter group and select it to use as parameter
   [image]
9. Add the Changed Date field to the filter group and select it to use as parameter
   [image]
10. Add the Previous State filed to report and set the default value not equal to "Unknown"
    [image]
11. Click Next
12. Select rows and values
    [image]
13. Select view options
    [image]
14. Report to use 
    [image]

Comment: This would have been a good tutorial except my analysis server is SQL 2012 Standard. So I don't get all the dimensions. All I have is Team System.  How would I do this with SQL standard and the Team system dimension.

Comment: OK I think I figured out how to do it with just the Team System. Working on step 13 at this point.

Comment: Is there some result?

Comment: It does produce results, I'm just not sure how to interpret them.  But it's at least a start at digging into the data.